# Inverse of a diagonal matrix with nonzero complex entries.

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, inverse

If $z_1,\dots,z_n$ are nonzero complex numbers, prove that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 & \\
 & \ddots \\
 & & z_n
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{z}_1/|z_1|^2 & \\
 & \ddots \\
 & & \bar{z}_n//|z_n|^2
\end{bmatrix}
=I_n.
$$

Comment: Have you tried multiplying those two matrices?

Comment: Say . Is the matrix product, then if A.A^(-1)=A^(-1).A=I, where I is the identity matrix, then you indeed have the inverse.

Comment: Ah, thanks, its been a while since I've done matrices so I didn't realise this. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has more to do with complex numbers than matrices.

If $z = a + ib$, then $z \bar{z} = a^2+b^2 = |z|^2$. Thus, if $z$ is nonzero (i.e., $|z| \ne 0$), then
$$
z\frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2} = 1.
$$
By virtue of the mechanics of matrix multiplication, in particular that of diagonal matrices, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 & \\
 & \ddots \\
 & & z_n
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{z}_1/|z_1|^2 & \\
 & \ddots \\
 & & \bar{z}_n//|z_n|^2
\end{bmatrix}
=I_n.
$$